# Can I tag other users when posting an image? Or was this removed?

Tags: .net, facebook-graph-api

I have a mobile app that uses the request with "me/photos" to post an attachment of my own Facebook page. This works great. Now I would like to include a friend's ID to tag with.

I have the ID. Can I still include the other user ID in a tag so the photo shows on their timeline? Or was this feature removed from the graph api? If it still works does someone have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the tags to a photo. Check the [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object on developers site.

[Here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/13849617/1343690) is a PHP code for the same. I hope you can write this in C#, since the logic is same.